# How can I display a value in a repeater without changing the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Title says it all really. I have a asp.net repeater, I want a way that I can display a string.empty instead of whatever data is actually there, but I want that data to remain unchanged. Any ideas?
C#:

```
foreach (var item in theContainer.Coverages.Values)
        {
            if (!item.IsCancelled)
            {
                if (Enumerations.Coverage.MainCoverages.Contains(item.Coverage))
                {
                    if (item.isScheduled == true)
                            //TODO code that displays a string.empty for limit
                    }
                    rpMainCoverages.DataSource = item.Coverage;
                }
            }
        };
```

And html:

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpMainCoverages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="BindItem">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCovName" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><asp:Label ID="lblDisplayLimit" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><asp:Label ID="lblDisplayPremium" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: so an empty string in place of those labels?

Comment: All those labels are already empty so what is the problem? But you can always use `OnItemDataBound` to set the label text as desired. Use `e.Item.FindControl("lblDisplayLimit")` to get them.

Comment: Yes, in the label with the id "lblDisplayLimit".

Comment: Can you clarify, if your data is empty then the repeater should display a `null` for the row?